# Given a port number, how to use netstat to find the connection detail?

Tags: linux, macos, networking, shell, port

I have a socket server code as below:

```
/*
** server.c -- a stream socket server demo
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10   // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(new_fd, "Hello, world!", 13, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It uses port 3490. When I run it on my Mac OS X, I try to use the netstat command to find this connection according to the port number:

```
netstat -anpt | grep 3490
```

the output is empty. What's the reason for it?

Comment: The standard first step in debugging a problem is to try to narrow it down.  In hardware, if you added seventeen devices to a machine, and it failed to boot, you would remove them, one at a time, until it worked again.  (Actually the smarter approach would be to add one thing at a time to begin with.)  Same principle applies in software: Do you still have your problem if you remove the forking and the signal handling?  Hardcode the addressing information?  Remove some of the loops?  Can you demonstrate the problem with a code sample that’s shorter than 127 lines (ideally, shorter than 32)?

Comment: Bottom line: If you want people to help you, don’t make them read through 127 lines of code to find the few that are relevant to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux and OS X's implementations of netstat are quite a bit different from each other, so you can't just take a netstat command that works on linux and expect it to work (let alone do the same thing) on OS X. In particular, OS X's netstat doesn't have a `-t` option, and it has `-p`, but it means something completely different from linux's (actually, on OS X, `-p` shows stats for the specified protocol, and since "t" isn't a recognized protocol, you should get an error from this command).

I presume the actual goal here is to find out about the process listening on port 3490? If so, OS X's netstat command can't do this; it has no capability to display information about the process attached to the port. For that, you need lsof: `lsof -itcp:3490`. Note that lsof cannot check processes you don't own; if the socket server is not running under your UID, you need to `sudo` the lsof command in order to see it.